# Save to html using utf 8

Tags: oracle, plsql, utl-file

I need to save a html file as utf 8. This is not about . Is this possible? In short my procedure is like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE MY_PROCEDURE
  IS

vFil  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
vFilNavn   varchar2(250);
vLinje  varchar2(32767);

begin
vFil := UTL_FILE.FOPEN ('MY_DIRECTORY',vFilNavn||'.tmp','w',32767);
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(vFil,vLinje);
    end;

   FOR recB in (select row from (my_html_content) );

loop 
vLinje := recB.Rad;
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(vFil,substr(vLinje,1,32767));    
end loop;   

UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(vFil);
UTL_FILE.FRENAME('MY_DIRECTORY',vFilNavn||'.tmp', 'MY_DIRECTORY',vFilNavn||'.html',TRUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR` instead of `UTL_FILE.FOPEN`.

See Oracle documentation [UTL_FILE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/u_file.htm#ARPLS70899):

> `UTL_FILE` expects that files opened by `UTL_FILE.FOPEN` in text mode are
>   encoded in the database character set. It expects that files opened by
>   `UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR` in text mode are encoded in the **UTF8 character
>   set**.
>
> **FOPEN_NCHAR Function**
>
> Even though the contents of an `NVARCHAR2` buffer may be AL16UTF16 or
>   UTF8 (depending on the national character set of the database), the
>   contents of the file are **always read and written in UTF8**.

Comment: I assume like this: vFil := UTL_FILE.FOPEN_NCHAR ('MY_DIRECTORY',vFilNavn||'.tmp','w',32767);

And also: UTL_FILE.PUT_NCHAR(vFil,substr(vLinje,1,32767)); ? Still I'm getting ORA-29298 Character set mismatch

Comment: Can you make a simple select on the data. Is the output correct?

Comment: Yes, it works fine without NCHAR. It is a html-code into varchar2. And the web-page also are as accepted. But the web-designer need the file to be saved as utf-8. My regional settings are Norwegian.